# IBM Worklight json store initialization

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to initialize a json store. While initialization I'm getting the following error:

```
BAD_PARAMETER_EXPECTED_ALPHANUMERIC_STRING
```

Can someone tell me how to correct this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your code and we can tell you for sure. But the short and obvious answer is you are passing in a value that's not alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

post your code.
checks the values that you give to the function. in the case that you use a parameters controls the quotes ""